# Understanding proof of fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

So this is the proof I have:

> If $p(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial, then there exists a $z \in \Bbb Z$ such that $p(z) = 0$.
>
> Let $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} +a_{n-2} z^{n-2} + ... + a_0$ where $n \in \Bbb N$ and $a_0, a_1, ..., a_{n-1} \in \Bbb C$. $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} p(z) = z^n[1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \frac{a_{n-2}}{z^2} + ... + \frac{a_0}{z^n}] = \infty$, so if $p(z)\neq 0$ for all $z \in   \Bbb C$, then define $f(z) = \frac{1}{p(z)}$ so $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z) = 0$.
>
> **Then there exists an $N > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq 1$ for all $\lvert z \rvert > N$.**

I don't understand how this bolded line is achieved or how it follows from the limit.

Continuing the proof:

> **Take the closed disk $\lvert z \rvert \leq N$. Since this disk is compact and $f$ is continuous, there exists an $M > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq M$ for all $\lvert z \rvert \leq N$.**

I don't understand what the disk has to do with anything, or how these inequalities follow from that disk, or why we are re-using the letter $N$ again.

Finishing the proof:

> Since $f(x)$ is bounded and entire, by Liouville $f(x)$ is a constant so $p(z)$ is a constant which is a contradiction.

I understand this ending but I don't understand the two previous lines.

Comment: It is just the definition of $\lim\limits_{|z|\to \infty}f(z)=0$ ($\epsilon-\eta$ type with $\epsilon=1$ and $N$ an integer greater than the corresponding $\eta$)

Comment: Why was $\epsilon = 1$ chosen?

Comment: Arbitrary choice we could have taken any $\epsilon$ it is just bounding the function for large $|z|$ is enough for our purpose

Comment: We see here *proof technique* at work: A few modest preliminary steps to cook up a situation where the real hammer, namely Liouville's theorem, can be applied.

Comment: @marwalix If we already bound the function by $1$ then why do we need to bound it again with $M$ in the line after that?

Comment: It is bound by $1$ for $|z|\gt N$ and on the compact $|z|\geq N$ $f$ is bounded. $M$ is the higher bound between $1$ and the supremum on the compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've collected the comments above.

So as stated we want to use Liouville's theorem on the function $f$. Thus we need to make sure that $f$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb C$. We do this in two steps.

1) Note that since $f$ has no zeros, and that $\lim_{z \to \infty}f(z)=0$. From the definition of limits we have that:
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \, \exists N(\epsilon) >0\quad  \mbox{such that } |z|>N(\epsilon) \Rightarrow |f(z)| < \epsilon.$$

Picking $\epsilon =1$ we have that: $|f(z)| < 1$ when $|z|>N(1)$.

2) Using the fact that $f$ is continuous everywhere it is naturally bounded on the disc $\overline {B(0,N(1))}$.

Using 1) and 2) we have that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb C$, and we may apply Louville's theorem.